# How to reduce git pack file size in local bare repository?

Tags: git, out-of-memory

I have a local bare clone of a git repository that contains some large files (I can't change anything in the origin repository). The initial pack file of the bare clone has over 6GB. This leads to out-of-memory exceptions when reading the local bare clone with jgit. I'm using git version 2.23.0.windows.1

I tried to repack the pack files in the local bare repo such that each file is smaller:

```
git config pack.packSizeLimit=2G
git repack -a -d
```

This works (there are more, smaller pack files) and the repo integrity is still ok (`git fsck`)

However, the bare repo is not synchronized with origin anymore. New commits are not shown after `git fetch`.

How can I modify the local bare repository such that it has smaller pack files and is still updated by `git fetch`? I can't change the origin repository.

Additional Info:
`git fetch` does download new data from the server. The output contains an `Unpacking objects` line etc. The line only appears if there are actually new commits on the server. This means the fetch works and the commits are stored locally, which is good.

`git log master` still does not show the new commits on master. I think the problem is that the `packed-refs` file is not updated. `grep master packed-refs` still shows the old commit for `refs/heads/master`. The `refs/heads/` folder is empty.

Comment: Unable to reproduce.  The local pack structure should have nothing to do with being "in sync' with the remote, and in my local tests following this procedure does not prevent fetching

Comment: Thank you for trying to reproduce the problem. I did some more tests and the problem still exists (I extended my post).